# Are bts, btr, btc instructions atomic for alligned memory operands?

Tags: assembly, x86

What's more to say? Just, are x86 `bts`, `btr`, `btc` instructions atomic for alligned memory operands, on more or less current chips (PIII+)?

Particularly. Is the following atomic when `ebx + n` is even?

```
BTS WORD PTR [ebx + n]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, read-modify-write instructions like this are never atomic.  An instruction like this is translated into micro-ops, RISC-like instructions that the execution engine actually executes.

You *can* make it atomic, give it the LOCK prefix.  Check volume 2A of the [Intel processor manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) for background info.

Comment: And what about `cmpxchg` and `xchg mem,reg` instructions?  Are they not atomic too?

Comment: I'm too lazy.  Please answer if you know the truth.

Comment: @HansPassant, does that mean, there is no way to avoid this 100 cycles consumed by `LOCK` to implement even a two instructions critical section? It is awful!

Comment: Sigh.  CMPXCHG requires LOCK to be atomic, XCHG is implicitly locked.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks!  So, I need to always prepend `cmpxchg` with `lock` for correct operations on multicore processors (Core2Duo+)?

Comment: @Number47 - not necessarily, read about Haswell's TSX - http://www.anandtech.com/show/6290/making-sense-of-intel-haswell-transactional-synchronization-extensions/2